# how to host a non html file using python

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, server, host

I want to host a non-html file using python. I know if i have a html/webpage I can just host it by the

```
python3 -m http.server
```

But I want something like I need to do some similar thing but I want to access some other file like

```
localhost:8000/<somefilename.nonhtml>
```

I need this because some other html file hosted in some other port number requires to access this file. But it takes in a url only.

If I use file:///<somefilename.nonhtml>, I am afraid that it will include some vulnerability.

Thus seeking for some suitable method. Please Help. Thanks in advance.

Regards..

Answer (score 0):

cd to the directory which you want to host/share the files. And run the command below. It should serve all files in that particular folder automatically.

```
python3 -m http.server
```

Any non HTML files will get listed too.

[image: HTTP server python]